# Counting data with multiple and variable filter

Tags: r, filter

I have a data frame df with multiple columns. I want to count the value for which a certain number of inequalities are met. With two given variables I would use :

```
res <- sum(df$column1 > x1 & df$column2 > x2)
```

However, I want it to be more flexible, taking a variable number of columns name and associated value like:

```
columns <- c("column1", "column2", ..., "columnn")
values <- c(x1, x2, ..., xn)
res <- sum(df$column1 > x1 & df$column2 > x2 & ... & df$columnn > xn)
```

How would I achieve such variable filtering efficiently with standard dataframes techniques ? (Dplyr syntax is nice, but it is usually too slow with my databases)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that each 'values' element correspond to a column in 'df', do the comparison of the corresponding column, element with `Map`, `Reduce` it to a single `logical` vector and get the `sum`

```
sum(Reduce("&", Map(">", df[columns], values)))
```

---

Or replicate the 'values' to get the lengths same as that of the dataset columns, do a comparison, get the `rowSums` of the logical `matrix`, check if it is equal to `length` of 'columns' and get the `sum` of the logical `vector`

```
sum(rowSums(df[columns] > rep(values, each = length(columns))) == length(columns))
```